# How to compare one dynamic list of dicts to another static list of dicts to find missing key value pair from dynamic list?

Tags: python

I have two lists of dictionaries as follows:

```
 l1 = [{'CreatedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 12, 12, 12, 46, 993000),DocumentCategory': '0.1 Admission Form'},  CreatedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 12, 12, 13, 53, 900000),DocumentCategory': '0.2 Doctor Notes'},CreatedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 12, 12, 14, 8, 817000), DocumentCategory': '0.3 Nurse Notes'},CreatedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 12, 12, 14, 42, 827000), DocumentCategory': '0.4 Lab Reports'}, CreatedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 12, 12, 15, 31, 57000), DocumentCategory': '0.5 Medical History'}, {'CreatedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 12, 12, 16, 14, 603000), 'DocumentCategory': '0.6 Medical Reports'}, CreatedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 13, 15, 2, 36, 643000),DocumentCategory': '0.7 Radiology'}, CreatedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 13, 15, 2, 54, 947000),  DocumentCategory': '0.8 Discharge Notes'}]

 l2 = [{'CreatedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 13, 10, 52, 27, 260000), DocumentCategory': '0.1 Admission Form'},CreatedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 13, 10, 53, 54, 103000),DocumentCategory': '0.2 Doctor Notes'}, CreatedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 13, 10, 53, 54, 460000), DocumentCategory': '0.3 Nurse Notes'},CreatedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 13, 10, 53, 54, 823000), DocumentCategory': '0.4 Lab Reports'},CreatedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 13, 10, 53, 54, 990000),DocumentCategory': '0.5 Medical History'},  {'CreatedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 13, 10, 53, 55, 240000), 'DocumentCategory': '0.6 Medical Reports'}]
```

I want to get only missing pair, In above case it should be:

```
missing = [{'CreatedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 13, 15, 2, 36, 643000), DocumentCategory': '0.7 Radiology'},{'CreatedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 13, 15, 2, 54, 947000), 'DocumentCategory': '0.8 Discharge Notes'}]
```

This is what I tried:

```
missing = [x for x in l2 if x not in l1]
```

However, this is only giving me matching pairs.

```
[{'CreatedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 13, 10, 52, 27, 260000), 'DocumentCategory': '0.1 Admission Form'}, {'CreatedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 13, 10, 53, 54, 103000), 'DocumentCategory': '0.2 Doctor Notes'}, {'CreatedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 13, 10, 53, 54, 460000), 'DocumentCategory': '0.3 Nurse Notes'}, {'CreatedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 13, 10, 53, 54, 823000), 'DocumentCategory': '0.4 Lab Reports'}, {'CreatedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 13, 10, 53, 54, 990000), 'DocumentCategory': '0.5 Medical History'}, {'CreatedOn': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 13, 10, 53, 55, 240000), 'DocumentCategory': '0.6 Medical Reports'}]
```

Comment: Are you looking for just mismatched keys in the dictionary, or also values?

Comment: What purpose does the list part serve? It looks like you only care about the contents of the (single) dictionary in the list

Comment: I am looking for list of mismatched pair(Key & Value)

Comment: If `l2` contains a key/value pair that isn't in `l1` should that be included in the results?

Comment: do you want them to be a list or dictionary? l1 and l2 both have a missing ], and making them a list seems redundant given what you seem to want in any case

Comment: actually l1 will always be constant, l2 may or may not have same elements. So looking to find key values which are not present in l2

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm with your particular example because of the numerous typos causing syntax errors, but the method you're using should work.

Using a basic example:

```py
l1 = [{'a':1,'b':2}, {'a':2,'b':3}]
l2 = [{'a':1,'b':2}, {'a':9,'b':10}]

missing = [x for x in l2 if x not in l1]
```

returns `[{'a': 9, 'b': 10}]`

Comment: Hi Joe, I have reviewed the question

Answer (score 0):

we can use a for loop. the dict from inside the list will be unpacked, so we can iterate on the items of the dict.

```
l1 = [{'name': 'Jon', 'Company': 'XYZ Ltd', 'age':45, 'LoggedIn': 'Yes'}]
l2 = [{'name': 'Jon', 'age':45}]
res = {}
for pair in l1[0].items():
    if pair[0] not in l2[0]:
        res.update({pair})
print(res)
```